# use MACRO __FUNCTION__ with inline function

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to add debug message in kmalloc function in linux kernel. So my goal is to print all functions that call kmalloc.

I tried to add

printk("caller : %s size : %d",**FUNCTION**, size);

in kmalloc function in slab.h

but, the result of **FUNCTION** is kmalloc itself. I realised that MACRO is processed first before inline function (fyi, kmalloc is an inline function).

Now, my question is, what is the simplest way to add debug message to kmalloc?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printk("%pS\n", __builtin_return_address(1)); /* or was it (0)? don't remember */
```

provided that you do not use `-fomit-frame-pointer` during compilation. If that turns out to not work, you can still use `dump_stack()`.

Comment: (0) is the current function, (1) will give the caller's address. Combining the returned address with `sprint_symbol()` should give the effect you want.

Comment: Totally cool. You learn something everyday. Thanks @user502515!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was working on Linux kernel and I wanted to do similar thing but for a different function. What I ended up doing was to rename the **FUNCTION** to **__FUNCTION** and add an extra char* parameter to it and then add a macro by the name FUNCTION as in the example below:

```
#define FUNCTION(i)  __FUNCTION(i,__FUNCTION__)

void __FUNCTION(int arg, char *func)
{
    printk("%s\n", func);
    //do what ever FUNCTION does
}
```

The macro needs to be defined in proper header file so that it is included in all source files using FUNCTION(). All calls to FUNCTION will then be substituted with __FUNCTION and print the caller. But, as in your case kmalloc is an inline function defined in a header file, you can simply add that macro above the function.